# Issue with add elements to List view in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application one select menu and list menu are there, I want to fill the values dynamically from DB. I am able to fill values in to select menu dynamically, but How can I fill it in list view, Can Any one tell me how to fill the values dynamically in list view, My is as follows,

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
 var opt  = '<option value="';
 opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
 opt += '">';
 opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
 opt += '</option>';
 $("#select-choice-location").append(opt);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<select name="select-choice-location" id="select-choice-location">
                  <option value="Select Location">Select Location</option>
   </select>
  <ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
       <li><a href="#">Select Location</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Select menu is working fine how to write same syntax for list view to get dynamic values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
 var opt  = '<li value="';
 opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
 opt += '">';
 opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
 opt += '</li>';
 $("#locationList").append(opt);
  }
```

Assigning click event

```
$(document).on('click','#locationList li',function(){

});
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Now How can I do on click event on <li> value

Comment: click event or <a> tag element

Comment: @user3300593 i added jquery click method

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a clean method for creating elements with attributes `jQuery(html, attributes)` ([Link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes))

Try using it to create your HTML and then append it to the necessary container:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
    // create and append the option tag
    $('<option/>', { value: res.rows.item(i).Location, text: res.rows.item(i).Location})
        .appendTo("#select-choice-location");

    // create and append the li tag
    $('<li/>', { text: res.rows.item(i).Location})
        .appendTo("#locationList");
}
```

[Similar Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YRC3G/)